# width and height img attribute values for devices with devicePixelRatio > 1 - should they be changed?

Tags: html, css, attributes, width, devicepixelratio

For devices with `window.devicePixelRatio == 1`

```
<img src="http://example.com/100x100.jpg" alt="image 100 by 100" width="100" height="100">
```

looks good: an image 100 by 100 pixels is used for the square of 100 by 100 - good.

For devices with `window.devicePixelRatio == 2` (a better quality of the image can be used for the same dimensions) what value supposed to be for width and height attributes - 100 or 200?

```
<img width="100" height="100" src="http://example.com/200x200.jpg" alt="image 200x200 for 100px by 100px">
```

or

```
<img width="200" height="200" src="http://example.com/200x200.jpg" alt="image 200x200 for 100px by 100px">
```

Should the img width and height attribute values be also updated based on `window.devicePixelRatio` or they should NOT be changed?

I can't find any clear information on this simple and basic question.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35880117/7683436). I beilieve it discusses your problem. Also, read [this medium article](https://elad.medium.com/understanding-the-difference-between-css-resolution-and-device-resolution-28acae23da0b) for more info.